# How to create snap slider in collection view with tilted effect in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, slider, carousel

I am trying to create a horizontal slider with work like carousel using collection view. Here is the image I need to copy:
[image]

It is a horizontal slider with N number of items.
I tried using FSPagerView and UPCarouselFlowLayout for this purpose but can't get exactly what I want. so, I tried creating it manually  using collection view but still it don't serve my need. Here is the code.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellC", for: indexPath)as! cellC
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let widthTotal = self.collview.frame.size.width - 40
        let widthRequired = widthTotal/3
        return CGSize(width: widthRequired, height: widthRequired)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if !decelerate {
            scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
    func scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell() {
        collview.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast
        let visibleCenterPositionOfScrollView = Float(collview.contentOffset.x + (collview.bounds.size.width / 2))
        var closestCellIndex = -1
        var closestDistance: Float = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        for i in 0..<collview.visibleCells.count {
            let cell = collview.visibleCells[i]
            let cellWidth = cell.bounds.size.width
            let cellCenter = Float(cell.frame.origin.x + cellWidth / 2)
            // Now calculate closest cell
            let distance: Float = fabsf(visibleCenterPositionOfScrollView - cellCenter)
            if distance < closestDistance {
                closestDistance = distance
                closestCellIndex = collview.indexPath(for: cell)!.row
            }
        }
        if closestCellIndex != -1 {
            collview.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: closestCellIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
        for cell in self.collview.visibleCells {
            let indexPath = collview.indexPath(for: cell)
            let cell = collview.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)as! cellC
            if indexPath!.row < closestCellIndex {
                //tilted effect on left side cell
                cell.bgview.backgroundColor = .red
            }
            if indexPath!.row > closestCellIndex {
                //tilted effect on right side cell
                cell.bgview.backgroundColor = .yellow
                let degrees = 30.0
                let radians = CGFloat(degrees * M_PI / 180)
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
            }
            if indexPath!.row == closestCellIndex {
                cell.bgview.backgroundColor = .green
                // no tilt effect on middle cell
                cell.transform = .identity
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone please explain how can I achieve exact thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use cocoapods namely "MMBannerLayout" to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue with implementing a carousel collection view without using pods, and after some exploration, I found a solution that worked for me. I noticed your question during my search, so I thought I'd share my resolution to help others facing the same challenge.

I've created a sample project that includes the UI and animations you're looking for. You can clone this project and customize it according to your needs. I've also put together a video tutorial demonstrating the implementation.

Sample Project Repository:
[GitHub](https://github.com/shakhzodsunnatov/CaruselCollectionView.git)

Image example:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o632N.png)

Feel free to explore the code and adapt it to your specific requirements. Good luck with your project, and I hope this solution proves helpful to everyone encountering a similar issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).